# MS access 2013 how can I programatically manipulate data from a form before inserting a record into a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

OK, This is my first time asking a question, so bear with me - its difficult to explain.

I am developing an Access Database application to replace functions and features that users have been doing using an excel Spreadsheet. The data on the Spreadsheet often gets corrupted due to various users incorrectly adding and/or modifying data. The Spreadsheet is basically 2 tables of data and a number of reports, each of which is a separate Sheet.

The idea behind the application is that the customer maintains an inventory of automobile Wheels(rims). Periodically these Wheels are placed on automatic testing machines and run through a test that produces CSV-formatted test data. The test data is manipulate in another application to produce a Spreadsheet containing rows of "RunOut" Data.

My Access application has 2 tables - a "WHEEL SPEC" Table with basic data about each wheel like name, size, storage location, etc, and a "RUNOUT HISTORY" Table where each record is one row of RunOut Data from the processing Spreadsheet.

The customer would like to be able to add RunOut Data to the RUNOUT HISTORY table by copying the Data rows from the processing Spreadsheet (usually 3 to 5 rows) And pasting them into the access table. I would like to set a foreign key field in each row to associate the data with an existing Wheel in the WHEEL SPEC table, and run some data validation before inserting to keep the data from getting corrupt as a result of the copy/paste operation. I have created a form with a combo box where the users can select the Wheel to associate with the new RunOut Data, a sub-form that allows them to paste the copied rows into the table, and two buttons "Commit" an "Cancel".

When the user selects "Commit", I would like to run validation on the copied data and then add the Wheel ID from the Wheel selected in the combo box to each record. I would like validation errors to report to the user without saving the data so they can decide whether to fix the data or Cancel and try again later.

Any help on this will be appreciated. I have looked for for solutions on-line, but most answers just refer to importing excel data which is not quite what I am trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have a Commit button that the user will click. When they do so, validate the data before allowing the post to the database to occur. If it passes, do the actual save to the DB; if it doesn't, don't allow it to be posted.

Comment: Do you want to use a bound or unbound form?

Comment: Where is the specific area you need help?  This reads more like a code request than an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a temp table to store the incoming data before moving it to the RunOut History table. Don't forget to include a WheelSpecID field. Here is one approach...

Create a sub form based off of the temp table. Make it a datasheet form so that the users can copy and paste from Excel into the datasheet.

Create a main form that is based off of the WheelSpec table. Insert the sub form onto this form, and link the Master and Child fields (WheelSpecID).

Here's the thing, you need the main form to load with the WheelSpecID, or have it change based off of your Combobox. The way it works, is anything put into the subform takes on the ID# of the main form. When you click your commit button you can run a check against each record from the temp table before moving the item over to your RunOut History table.

Comment: Craig - Thanks, this is a great suggestion, and along the lines of where I was heading on my own before I got stuck and decided to ask for help. That makes me believe I am on the right track.